# Clear cell contents based on color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to write a script that if a cell color is red, it will be deleted. I have found the answer for excel but not google sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for that. You might need to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
function deleteCellsDependingOnColor() {
    var colorToDelete = '#ff0000';
    var gs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sn = gs.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var data = sn.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
            var cellBgColor = sn.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).getBackground();
            if (cellBgColor === colorToDelete) {
                sn.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
                //for clearing values only use
                //sn.getRange(r+1,c+1).clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

use method `deleteCells()` only if you actually want to delete cells, you want to delete values and background color only, use `clear()` method

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to delete the cell entirely. Any way to just delete the contents of the cell?

Comment: as mentioned use `sn.getRange(r+1,c+1).clear();` instead of `sn.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);`

Comment: @Ricardas well done. But you're calling `getBackground()` for every cell in the table. It's a quite time consuming operation. There is the official recommendation to use a 2D array to get all data at once and process the array without redundant calls to the server: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices It works much faster

Comment: @Yuri Khristich your solution of course is much better if performance is critical! And if it's not critical, it's still better :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that uses [the best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices):

```
function myFunction() {
  var color = '#ff0000';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();               // get all data
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();   // get all backgrounds

  // check the backgrounds and change the data
  for (let row in data) for (let col in data[0]) {
    if (backgrounds[row][col] == color) data[row][col] = '';
  }
  
  range.setValues(data);  // set the data back on the sheet
}
```

It grabs all data on the sheet as a 2D array, changes the array, and put the modified array back on the sheet all at once.

Comment: you solution leaves background colors untouched, not sure what the question giver wanted, but adding `backgrounds[row][col] = '#ffffff';` and `.setBackgrounds(backgrounds)` to your code accordingly, colors also would reset to default white.

Comment: @Ricardas Yes. You're right. I hope here will be any reaction from OP.